# Команда для вывода топ 10 приложений, использующих ОЗУ системы

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnu

Желаемо в `terminale` при вводе `top10` выводился список 10 самых память потребляемых приложений. Наподобие:

```
1  firefox 1025Mb 
2  chrome  800Mb 
3  apache  600Mb
...
10 nginx   100Mb
```

Comment: а в диспетчере сортировать по ОЗУ  нельзя ?
 (знаю что в Ubuntu можно, в остальных не знаю)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Как отсортировать вывод - уже показали. Но только оно решает немного другую задачу:) Решим задачу правильно.

Для начала выведем то, что нас просили

```
ps -e -o rss,command | awk '{arr[$2]+=$1}END {for (i in arr) print i"\t"arr[i]/1024"Mb"}' | sort -k 2 -n -r | head | nl
```

Разберем по "пайпам" (палочкам).

- вначале выведем список процессов и сколько памяти они скушали.
- потом awk магия поможет нам сделать "group by". Это нужно потому, что некоторые процессы (например, хром)  любят разбиваться на сотни мелких процессов. И вроде память не кушают, а памяти нет. Также awk преобразует это в мегабайты
- потом sort все нам красиво отсортирует по колонке с памятью.
- head отберет 10 толстых и nl добавит счетчик.

Последний шаг. Хочется, чтобы команда `top10` была доступна. Воспользуемся псевдонимом (алиасом):

```
alias top10='ps -e -o rss,command | awk '"'"'{arr[$2]+=$1}END {for (i in arr) print i"\t"arr[i]/1024"Mb"}'"'"' | sort -k 2 -n -r | head | nl'
```

Теперь в эмуляторе терминале доступна команда `top10`, но после перезапуска эмулятора терминала, она пропадет. Для того, чтобы она не пропадала, нужно добавить наш новый алиас в конфигурационный файл вашей оболочки (bash, zsh, fish и т.д.) и обновить его (в зависимости от вашей оболочки), например:
`source .bashrc` или `source .zshrc`.

Comment: RSS — это не про ОЗУ, это больше про адресное пространство.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте следующую команду:

```
ps aux --sort -rss
```

[Здесь](http://alvinalexander.com/linux/unix-linux-process-memory-sort-ps-command-cpu) вы можете узнать больше об использовании памяти в Linux

Answer (score 2):

Если вас интересует сколько памяти освободится, если убить процесс, то вам нужна величина USS ("Unique Set Size"), а не RSS ("Resident Set Size"), показываемый ps/top.

USS может выводить [`smem` утилита](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/smem.8.html):

```
smem --sort=uss --reverse --abbreviate --columns="name uss" --no-header | head | nl
```

Пример вывода:

```
 1  thunderbird                356.6M 
 2  compiz                     343.2M 
 3  firefox                    318.6M 
 4  emacs                      279.5M 
 5  calibre                    158.1M 
 6  yandex_browser             154.0M 
 7  chromium-browse            150.5M 
 8  dropbox                    125.4M 
 9  yandex_browser             125.4M 
10  yandex_browser              92.1M
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ps axo pid,rss,cmd --sort=-rss | head -n 11 | tail -n +2
```

`"-"` перед rss, отсортирует по убыванию;

`-n 11` потому что выведет шапку первой строкой и только потом 10 процессов

`-n +2` чтобы вывести со второй строки